# GDI+: How to fill a triangle?

Tags: gdi+, linear-gradients

i want to fill the bottom-left half of a a rectangle (i.e. a triangle):

[image]

with a LinearGradient, going from color to transparent:
[image]

Filling half a rectangle:

[image]

i know the point (x,y), and the size of the rectangle.

If i try using a [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534473(v=VS.85).aspx), to perform my linear gradient:

```
brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
      MakePoint(0, y), //bottom left corner
      MakePoint(x, 0), //upper right corner
      MakeColor(255, c), //fully opaque color
      MakeColor(0, c)); //fully transparent color
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, MakeRect(0, 0, w, h));
```

The linear gradient brush fills the entire rectangle, which would be fine if it continued to fill the rest of the rectangle with the final (transparent) color; but instead it wraps around:

[image]

i have my `LinearGradientBrush` how i like, i just want to `FillTriangle` or `FillPolygon`, rather than `FillRectangle`. Except there is no FillTriangle or FillPolygon, only FillRectangle, and FillEllipse.

## See also

[link text](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18057/simpler-solution-to-this-geometry-trig-problem)

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? I definately see a FillPolygon method within the graphics object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89sks199.aspx

Comment: What what do you know, there *is* one. i swore i could only find `FillRectangle` and `FillEllipse`. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535958(v=VS.85).aspx)  Although, i'm not using .NET, this is GDI+. Rephrase that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: +1 I had the same question, I found this on Google. So +1, us morons have to stick together!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a FillPolygon in the Graphics library. I think you should be able to do it like this:

```
brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
      MakePoint(x, y), 
      MakePoint(0, h), 
      MakeColor(255, c), //fully opaque color
      MakeColor(0, c)); //fully transparent color

graphics.FillPolygon(brush, new PointF[] {
        new PointF(0, 0),
        new PointF(0, h),
        new PointF(w, h)
    });
```

Comment: Even though i'm a moron, i think the question can still be helpful, since `FillTriangle` can be implemented as `FillPolygon). And although your syntax in probably for .NET, it can be translated to GDI+ easily enough.